# Eclipse: std symbol could not be resolved, Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, std, toolchain

I am trying to get my Eclipse editor up and running, but I have this error whenever I try to create an empty project:
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved

When I create a "Hello World C++ Project" there is no error, but when I create an empty project this error appears.

I have looked at the include files, the symbols and path options, and a few other places. I can not find any difference between the two projects. I have tried exporting settings from a working project into the current one and it does not work. I have the most recent version of XCode (4.5.1) installed. For my toolchain I chose the MacOSX GCC.

My code couldn't be simpler:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked several other questions and none of them have helped me resolve my issue. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a warning on the #include? I'd bet it's an include path problem.